Golden Ration in Equilateral Triangle, Power of a Point Theorem question
Does anyone know how the Power of a Point Theorem is used to get line segment AF in the following picture?  Also how the length of AE (which requires knowing sides of equilateral triangle, which a circle of radius 1 is circumscribed is in) is found?
I understand FH is 1, confused on finding AE, I understand Power of a Point theorem as shown below however am having trouble applying it her to solve for AF.
Problem:

ref: website
Another graphic which is related to Golden Ratio, not sure if outdoor circle helps Power of a Point theorem:

Theorem:

ref:website
The ratio of the circumradius to the side length of an equilateral triangle is $1:2\cos\dfrac{\pi}{6}=1:\sqrt{3}$.  Let the blue hypotenuse equal 1 and $\cos$ is shown in blue horizontal, then multiply this by 2 to get the equilateral triangle side length.  The red line is $\cos\dfrac{\pi}{6}$.

Further shown by rotating the same hexagonal grid, take the blue hypotenuse circumradius equal to 1 and the red part of the equilateral triangle multiplied by 2 equal to $\sqrt 3$.

The ratio of the inscribed radius to the side length of an equilateral triangle is $1:2\tan\dfrac{\pi}{3}=1:2\sqrt{3}$.
The following figure shows this where the inscribed equilateral triangle is rotated.  A blue line is drawn showing $O = {\sqrt 3}$ and $A = 1$.  $\frac {O} {A} = \sqrt 3$, now multiply $\sqrt 3 * 2$ to get inscribed equilateral triangle side length, ${GF}$.

$\vec {GF} = {FH} = {HG} = 1$ then ${AB} = {BC} = {CA} = 2$ because using the same equilateral triangle grid and look at ${AB} = 2 * {GF}$.

Using case 3 of the power point theorem, $E = D(A), A=P, F=C, H=B$, then $FA = x$, $EA = 1$.  Power point theorem: ${HA} * {FA} = {EA}^2$.  $x(x+1) = 1$, $x^2 + x - 1 = 0$.  This is the solution to the quadratic equation:  $x = \frac {\sqrt 5 - 1}{2}$.  Now the golden ratio is $\frac {FH}{AF} = \frac {1}{AF} = \frac {2} {\sqrt 5 - 1} = 1.61...$.

The ratio of the circumradius to the side length of an equilateral triangle is $1:2\cos\dfrac{\pi}{6}=1:\sqrt{3}$ and the ratio of the inscribed radius to the side length of an equilateral triangle is $1:2\tan\dfrac{\pi}{3}=1:2\sqrt{3}$. Now since $\Delta FGH$ is equilateral, by symmetricity we have $$FG=1\implies AB=2\implies AE=1$$
For the power theorem, it is actually case 3 because $AE$ is tangent to the cirucmcircle of $\Delta FGH$ at $E$. (If you use the figure of the theorem you quoted, then $E=D,A=P,F=C,H=B$).

This seems to explain it.  I added another drawing to the end.  For $FG =1, AB =2, AE = 1$ I start in the center of the drawing look at FG, then associated this a level out to CA through similarity, I note $2\sqrt 3$, then as seen in red, the outmost triangle side is $\sqrt 3$.  Is this ok to establish $FG, AB, AE$ or should I be using some other method or theorem?

@Nick your photo is kind of unclear, so I cannot follow your argument. While my usual approach for circumradius-argument is to connect the vertex (Let's say $X$) with the circumcenter $O$, and also consider the projection of circumcenter on the side (which should be exactly the midpoint also, I write $Y$ ), then $\Delta XOY$ is right-angled and $\angle OXY=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$, so thats why I get the ratio. Similar approach for the inscribed radius.

I updated the OP.  I used an equilateral triangle grid to show the argument, unsure if this is the best way.  I'm still unclear on two things maybe you can clear up.  How is $\Delta FGH$ equilateral by symmetricity?  Is this some theorem?  Also, I get $\frac {2}{\sqrt 5 - 1} = \frac {FH}{AF}$ instead of OP $\frac {1+\sqrt 5}{2} = \frac {FH}{AF}$, both have the same result, do you know why the forms are different?

Two ratio you written are the same and you can check by rationalizing them. For the equiliateral stuff,  I admit thats my typing mistake, what I mean should be, "Since, $\Delta FGH$ is equilateral, now we apply symmetrical argument on the ratio we discussed above, we have $FG=1,\cdots$" Sorry for the unconvenient caused. The equilateral of $FGH$ is by assumption in the question.
